# Getting 401 in secondary Laravel api requests

Tags: laravel, api

I have created som api routes to interact with a laravel app I made, I mannualy login the user with default credentials and return the logged page, but when the user tries to make another request from inside the logged app it returns 401 in all requests.

Comment: it's not possible to help you with this few information... please post you routes file at least...

Answer (score 0):

if you defined your route inside api.php it uses another middlewares then web.php.

so when you are using default laravel auth for login and you want authenticate your api request by session define it insude web.php or change middleware in api.php